# Installing RRDtool in windows 8 (64bit)

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I am new to Round robin database and I read the articles for getting an idea about RRDtool. Please anyone suggest some articles or give instructions to install RRDtool in windows 8 (64bit).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

since rrdtool is a system tool most people use on unix-ish platforms, you may actually have more fun, getting a virtual ubuntu up and running (using VirtualBox) and then doing

```
apt-get install rrdtool
```

instead of going through the tribulations of setting up a unix tool on windows.

To learn about rrdtool, I recommend you take a look at the tutorials on the rrdtool website. http://www.rrdtool.org

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/christiankrausse/projekte/perl/rrdtool-v1-4-8-win32-binaries-rrds-for-active-state-perl-5-16-2-windows

Comment: "rrdtool is a system tool most people use on unix-ish platforms" Source ??